# Adding tab bar with 3 items to a view based application

Tags: iphone, xcode, tabs

So, right now I had created a view-based application with 8 different views. I want it to show a tab bar on 3 of the views. This tab bar would have 3 items, which will allow the user to switch to the 3 said views.

How should I go about doing so? Thanks a lot.

AppDelegate.h

```
@interface LoginPageAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    LoginPageViewController *viewController;
    UITabBarController *tabBarController;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet LoginPageViewController *viewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;


@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    tabBarController.delegate=self;

    RequestPage* requestPage = [[RequestPage alloc] init];  
    UIViewController *RequestPageView = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:requestPage];  

    StatusPage* statusPage = [[StatusPage alloc] init];  
    UIViewController *StatusPageView = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:statusPage];  
    NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:RequestPageView, StatusPageView, nil]; 
    tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;

    [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];        

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

RequestPage.m

```
- (id)init {
    self.title = @"Request Page";
    UIImage* anImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"];
    UITabBarItem* theItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Request Page" image:anImage tag:2];
    self.tabBarItem = theItem;
    [theItem release];
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to start with view based application. And then create a `UITabbarController` in you `appDelegate` file.

Appdelegate.h

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController;
// set properties
```

Appdelegate.m

```
// Synthsize

tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.delegate=self;

//Adding Search,Nearby,Map,AboutUs,Favorites Tabs to tabBarController  
Search * search = [[Search alloc] init];  
UINavigationController *searchNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:search];  

Nearby* nearby = [[Nearby alloc] init];  
UINavigationController *nearbyNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nearby];  

Map* map = [[Map alloc] init];  
UINavigationController *mapNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:map];  

AboutUs* aboutUs = [[AboutUs alloc] init];  
UINavigationController *aboutUsNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:aboutUs];  

Favorites* favorites = [[Favorites alloc] init];  
UINavigationController *favoritesNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:favorites];  

NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:searchNav,nearbyNav,mapNav,aboutUsNav,favoritesNav, nil];  
tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;  

[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
```

You can accordingly manage in which tab you want to place navigation controller or only a view controller.

Then in each of the view controllers mentioned above you need to implement

```
- (id)init {}
```

in which you can set Tab name and image.

**Update**:

```
- (id)init {
        self.title = @"Second";
        UIImage* anImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"];
        UITabBarItem* theItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Second" image:anImage tag:2];
        self.tabBarItem = theItem;
        [theItem release];
    return self;
}
```

Comment: How do I set the tab name & images?

Comment: Thank you for the prompt replies. I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Am really new in this. I edited my question with what I did, please do take a look. The app crashes during launch.

Comment: Which portion have you updated? Is my solution working for you or is your application still crashing?

Comment: You are missing **NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:searchNav,nearbyNav,mapNav,aboutUsNav,favoritesNav, nil]; tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;**

Comment: I edited my question with your solutions(if I did it correctly).

Comment: And no need of self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;

Comment: @Nitish let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2090/discussion-between-matakazer-and-stone)

Answer (score 1):

Its better to create a Tabbar-based application along with UINavigationController to navigate multiple views.

Comment: Gonna be tedious to start afresh again. Since I had no problem navigating, I was trying to look for a quick solution to this problem.

Comment: No need to start a fresh from top to bottom. You just have to copy and paste your created views in a newly created tabbar based application so that you don't have to bother and manage so many manual code. Anyways...